# Convert timestamp from milliseconds to Date or Calendar in local time zone

Tags: java

I get a string with a millisecond and a timezone like this "1353913216000+0000", so a UTC time basically. How can I convert this to my local time? I do not think i can use a DateFormat, there is no millisecond pattern.

Comment: is the tmiezone always 0, or could it be something else?

Comment: According to the Javadoc for `SimpleTimeStamp`, `S` is the millisecond marker: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @JohnB - i believe S is only for _fractional_ milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the class Calendar

```
    Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2"));
    c.setTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));


    System.out.println(new Date(c.getTimeInMillis()+TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2").getOffset(c.getTimeInMillis())));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use one of the built-in parsers, you could do the following:

1. parse out the number up to the `+` and convert to a long.
2. create a `Date` instance using this number
3. Use a date format that ends with `+zone` to convert the date to a string
4. replace the time zone with the one from the input
5. parse the new string with the same date format